# Android Copy and Paste Multiple Text

Tags: android, listview, clipboard

I have used android clipboard manager to copy and paste text. Like whatsapp, i would like to copy multiple text from listview and paste those.
I am able to do like this,

```
StringBuilder textMessage = new StringBuilder();
for(messsage) {
 textmessage.append(message);
 textmessage.append("\n"); 
}
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", textMessage.toString());
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Instead of appending the multiple textmessages into one, can i able to store the array of textmessages into one clip object and retrive using array indices.

Comment: Just make an Arraylist of Strings... I don't understand the problem

Comment: ClipData.newPlainText doesn't take arraylist of Strings as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you could add multiple `ClipData.Item` to your `ClipData`. So instead of using static method `newPlainText`, create your new `ClipData` using

```
ClipData(ClipDescription description, ClipData.Item item)
```

or any other constructor available.

I have used `getItemCount` method of `ClipData` to demonstrate that it is indeed a indexed list of values, so you can definitely use `getItemAt` to fetch any `ClipData.Item` from any position, provided position is not leading you to `OutOfBoundException`. Below code is very novice, but would serve the purpose of demonstration I believe. Let me know if you need any more help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ClipboardManager clipboard;
    static int var = 0;
    ClipData clipData;
    TextView tvClip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvClip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_add);

        clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

        Button btnClip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btnClip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item("var" + var);
                if (clipData == null) {
                    clipData = new ClipData(new ClipDescription("your_clip_description", new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}), item);
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
                }
                clipData.addItem(item);
            }
        });

        Button showClip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show);
        showClip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clipData != null)
                    tvClip.setText("count = " + clipData.getItemCount());
            }
        });
    }
}
```