# Paste from android clipboard manager

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

If saved many strings like: s1, s2, s3, ... in my clip board and s1 is last item that saved. I want to paste s2. I used this code for pasting s1:

```
myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData abc = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
ClipData.Item item1 = abc.getItemAt(0);
ClipData.Item item2 = abc.getItemAt(1);
String text =  item2.getText().toString();
textview.setText(text);
```

also I used `abc.getItemAt(1)` and not worked.

Please help me.Thanks alot

log:

```
    E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
    E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Invalid index 1, size is 1 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251) at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304) at android.content.ClipData.getItemAt(ClipData.java:790)
```

Comment: Which android version did you try it on?

Comment: not worked means error? or wrong result?

Comment: What is the type of `item2` in your code? and where are you assigning it?

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak android 4.1 api 16

Comment: @imudin07 error and crashed app

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak I edited qusetion

Comment: can you check this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671161/android-copy-and-paste-multiple-text

Comment: Please put logcat of error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid index 1, size is 1 at java.util.ArrayList....

It means that there is only 1 item in your `Clipboard` (size is 1). So getting the item at index 1 will throw an exception.

Please check the way you copy your data to the clipboard. For some reason, your clipboard is having only 1 item.

One thing you can do to prevent the Exception from occurring is to check the number of items in clipboard using `abc.getItemCount()`

```
if (abc.getItemCount() > 1) {
    ClipData.Item item2 = abc.getItemAt(1);
    String text =  item2.getText().toString();
    textview.setText(text);
} else {
    textview.setText("Only one item present in clipboard");
}
```